# Serve files from local storage in React Native App

Tags: javascript, expo, react-native

I have scoured the Internet but couldnt find a solution for my problem and as such would be grateful for any help or directions as to how to acomplish my goal or if it is even possible to do so.

So the problem I am trying to solve is as follows:
In my application I let user select files using Expo DocumentPicker and want to get the using fetch over http in other part of the application.
Is it possible to setup a localhost http server inside the react native appliction form which it will be posible to serve the aforementioned files? If so what is the best way to do so?

I have struggled with this for some days now and will be thankfull for any help offered.

Comment: Please try to explain what is your goal. 
I don‘t think it‘s necessary to setup a an Webserver running on the mobile device.

Comment: I want to enable user to load a tfjs model form localstorage but as far as I am aware the only possible way to load tfjs model in RN is to either bundle files at compilation or fetch the model files over http.

Comment: I have no experience with tensor flow. But why you shouldn‘t be able to save a file in your apps data folder?

Comment: it's because tfjs has two ways of loading a model either from bundled resources or via http fetch, so the only way I see to load a model from device is to takie it and serve on a localhost webserver